# Apache 2 restart error / owncloud

Tags: apache2

i tried to use owncloud but i cannot access to my server (localhost/database is not found). I realized apache 2 is not working currently. I got this errors :

[image]

How can i fix this problem ? Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

As written in the error message, there seems to be no /var/log/apache2 directory or it is not writeable for the user running your apache daemon.

Comment: There is no folder called "apache2" in /var/log. But it is in /etc

Comment: That's the reason why I and the error message told you this :) Just create it and check that the permissions are fine for the apache user to write into the new directory. Than restart the Webserver.